# Is there any other good documentation for Metrics Codahale

Tags: java, ehcache, metrics

In the net i'm unable to find more details for the Metrics tutorial or example. Even the Metrics site itself have very minimum level of details. Could any one can provide the better documentation link or examples link ?

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: I would say that the [documentation](http://metrics.codahale.com/manual/) is pretty good (unless you're referring to another site?) - what aspect are you having trouble with?

Comment: In the user manual, For each type of instrumenting and reporting there is no detail documentation or example. The new user will surly stuck out there